# Textbox and Datagridview Combine then Send to Mysql C# VisualStudio Code

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview

Can anyone help me i dont have any idea on how to combine the textbox and the datagrid in C#

I have a Textbox of

| Example |  |
| --- | --- |
| Transaction No | 123456 |
| Name | Jonjon Candare |
| Section | IT Staff |
| DateNeeded | 2021-04-21 |

then i have a datagridview

| QTY | ITEM DESC | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CD | $3 |
| 1 | DVD | $250 |

I want the two combine the items in the datagridview and the transactionno,name,section and date needed in MYSQL

in get this in mysql

| Transaction No | Name | Section | DateNeeded | QTY | ITEM DESC | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Jonjon Candare | IT Staff | 2021-04-21 | 1 | CD | $3 |
| 123456 | Jonjon Candare | IT Staff | 2021-04-21 | 1 | DVD | $250 |

CAN ANYONE HELP ME PLSSS IN THE CODE ANY C# SAMPLES THERE LIKE THIS ONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following code to combine the data from textbox and datagirdview and insert it to the database.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = @"";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            connection.Open();
            string sqlcommand = "insert into Product(Transaction_No,Name,Section,DateNeeded,QTY,ITEM_DESC,AMOUNT) values(@Transaction_No,@Name,@Section,@DateNeeded,@QTY,@ITEM_DESC,@AMOUNT)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlcommand, connection);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_DESC", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transaction_No", Convert.ToInt32(txtNo.Text));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", txtsection.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNeeded", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
                
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNo.Text = "123456";
            txtName.Text = "Jonjon Candare";
            txtsection.Text = "IT Staff";
            txtDate.Text = "2021-04-21";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "QTY");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "ITEM DESC");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "AMOUNT");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "CD", "$3");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "DVD", "$250");
        }
```

Also, I create the table by using the following sql sentence.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [Transaction_No] INT NULL, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Section] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [DateNeeded] DATE NULL, 
    [QTY] INT NULL, 
    [ITEM_DESC] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [AMOUNT] NVARCHAR(50) NULL 
)
```

Last but not least, I don't suggest that you create the filed name that contains space, such as `Transaction No`, which may cause the sql error. so I changed it to `Transaction_No`.

Tested result:

[image]